# How to select the last data? Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Have tables Employees и Invoice.

```
Employees:                              Invoice:
id_emp    name      id_invoice          id_invoice   date_invoice
-------------------------------         ------------------------------
1         Peter     5                   5            01.01.2014 10:56 
2         Alfred    6                   6            02.04.2014 11:21
3         Jack      7                   7            03.09.2014 12:32
2         Alfred    8                   8            10.10.2014 16:43
```

How can I get all the employees and their only last invoices, ie in the form:

```
id_emp    name      id_invoice   date_invoice
------------------------------------------------------
1         Peter     5            01.01.2014 10:56 
3         Jack      7            03.09.2014 12:32
2         Alfred    8            10.10.2014 16:43
```

I tried to do:

```
SELECT id_emp, name, emp.id_invoice, max(date_invoice) as date_invoice 
   FROM Employees emp, Invoice inv 
     WHERE emp.id_invoice = inv.id_invoice GROUP BY id_emp, name, emp.id_invoice;
```

But it doesn't work as I want.

Comment: Your data model is not good, you might want to avoid the redundancy in `Employees`.

Comment: @ammoQ I think there is no redundancy in the schema. can you elaborate some more plz.

Comment: table Employees like history table

Comment: There seems to be a dependency between `id_emp` and `name`, but `id_emp` is apparently not the primary key since there are duplicate values (2nd and 4th row).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below Query will help you.You also need to grouping of id_invoice.

```
SELECT id_emp, name, MAX(emp.id_invoice) AS id_invoice, 
  max(date_invoice) as date_invoice 
FROM Employees emp, Invoice inv 
WHERE emp.id_invoice = inv.id_invoice GROUP BY id_emp, name;
```

Comment: It should work as per your case.What is output of above query and what you expect ?

Comment: The problem with this answer is, that it only works if the id_invoice and date_invoice is guaranteed both to be ascending in such a manner that when the date of one invoice is greater than the date of another invoice, then the id is *also* greater. If it is possible for an invoice with a greater date to have a smaller id, then this approach fails, and you need to add the KEEP clause to either the id or the date (depending on which one you wish to use for ordering.)

Answer (score 2):

When you do GROUP BY and need to include more columns from "the last" invoice, KEEP syntax can be very handy:

```
with employees as (
   select 1 id_emp, 'Peter' name, 5 id_invoice from dual
   union all
   select 2, 'Alfred', 6 from dual
   union all
   select 3, 'Jack', 7 from dual
   union all
   select 2, 'Alfred', 8 from dual
), invoice as (
   select 5 id_invoice, to_date('01.01.2014 10:56','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') date_invoice from dual
   union all
   select 6, to_date('02.04.2014 11:21','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')from dual
   union all
   select 7, to_date('03.09.2014 12:32','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')from dual
   union all
   select 8, to_date('10.10.2014 16:43','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')from dual
)
select emp.id_emp
     , max(emp.name) name
     , max(inv.id_invoice) keep (dense_rank last order by inv.date_invoice) last_id_invoice
     , max(inv.date_invoice) last_date_invoice
  from employees emp
  join invoice inv
      on inv.id_invoice = emp.id_invoice
 group by emp.id_emp
 order by emp.id_emp
```

Group by id_emp. (I assume id_emp is a primary key and emp.name is redundant, therefore I use max(name) - if id_emp is not a key, then include it in the group by.)

The last invoice date we get with an ordinary max() function. Getting the id_invoice for the invoice that has the last date is done with the KEEP syntax - using DENSE_RANK LAST order by inv.date_invoice tells the max(inv.id_invoice) function that it should only take the max() of those rows that have the LAST date_invoice.

An alternative method is using analytic functions like for example:

```
with employees as (
   select 1 id_emp, 'Peter' name, 5 id_invoice from dual
   union all
   select 2, 'Alfred', 6 from dual
   union all
   select 3, 'Jack', 7 from dual
   union all
   select 2, 'Alfred', 8 from dual
), invoice as (
   select 5 id_invoice, to_date('01.01.2014 10:56','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') date_invoice from dual
   union all
   select 6, to_date('02.04.2014 11:21','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')from dual
   union all
   select 7, to_date('03.09.2014 12:32','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')from dual
   union all
   select 8, to_date('10.10.2014 16:43','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')from dual
)
select id_emp, name, id_invoice, date_invoice
  from (
   select emp.id_emp
        , emp.name
        , inv.id_invoice
        , inv.date_invoice
        , row_number() over (
             partition by emp.id_emp
             order by inv.date_invoice desc
          ) rn
     from employees emp
     join invoice inv
         on inv.id_invoice = emp.id_invoice
  )
 where rn = 1
 order by id_emp
```

Both methods have the advantage of not accessing tables more than once. The second method using analytic row_number() function is the easiest if you need many columns from "the last" row - in such cases KEEP method requires copying the same KEEP clause in many columns.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to [`rank`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm) the invoices:

```
SELECT id_emp, name, id_invoice
FROM   (SELECT id_emp, name, emp.id_invoice, 
               RANK()  (ORDER BY date_invoice PARTITION BY id_emp) AS rk
        FROM   Employees emp
        JOIN   Invoice inv ON emp.id_invoice = inv.id_invoice)
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Comment: emp.id_invoice alias does not survive the inline view, rank() can produce multiple rn = 1

Comment: fixed the `emp.` issue. Wrt `rank` - `row_number` could be used instead, but this is a business logic question - how should two invoices with the same date be handled?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the latest invoice number instead of the latest invoice date since there can be two invoices on the same day

Also as per your data you can identify the latest invoice based on its invoice number.Try this:-

```
SELECT id_emp, name, max(emp.id_invoice), date_invoice
FROM Employees emp, Invoice inv 
WHERE emp.id_invoice = inv.id_invoice GROUP BY id_emp, name, date_invoice;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
    SELECT id_emp, name, emp.id_invoice, max(date_invoice) as date_invoice 
       FROM Employees emp , Invoice inv 
    WHERE 
emp.id_emp = inv.id_emp 
AND inv_id_invoice = (
      SELECT MAX(id_invoice) from Invoices c where c.id_emp = inv.id_emp
)
```